# Why is the underlying command of "select all" not working when executed with python? (Grease Pencil)

Tags: python, scripting, select

While in edit mode of a grease pencil object, the tooltip of "select all" says that the corresponding python command would be `bpy.ops.gpencil.select_all(action='SELECT')`.
This is also confirmed by the Info Editor.

But when I try to run this command while in edit mode (either from the Python Console or in a script), it doesn't select anything.

For example this code doesn't work (if the vertices weren't already selected):

```
import bpy

# change to edit mode
bpy.ops.gpencil.editmode_toggle()

# select all vertices (doesn't work)
bpy.ops.gpencil.select_all(action="SELECT")

# move the selected vertices
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-0.5, 0, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I use blender 2.90.1 (same behavior occurred in blender 2.91.0 Alpha).

Comment: This looks like it "should" work. Can show how to get and set the `points` of a grease pencil's stroke using the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To do with API methods**

*As commented, the code used looks like it "should" work. Have answered showing a low level alternative to move the gp data points.*

Move all points of all strokes of all frames of all layers of the gp object's data.

Narrow down using active frame or layer if required.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
from bpy import context

ob = context.object

gp = ob.data
active_layer = gp.layers.active
active_frame = active_layer.active_frame
for layer in gp.layers:
    for frame in layer.frames:
        for stroke in frame.strokes:
            for p in stroke.points:
                p.co += Vector((0.5, 0, 0))
```

**Selecting via operator appears to need 3D view area for context.**

Can select all the gp data via operator, by overriding the context to include the 3D view area, eg

```
import bpy

# assume is in EDIT mode
for a in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if a.type == 'VIEW_3D':

        # select all vertices (doesn't work)
        bpy.ops.gpencil.select_all(action="SELECT")
        # run in 3d area or override context to "pretend" in 3d area works.
        bpy.ops.gpencil.select_all({"area" : a}, action="SELECT")
        break
```

However the transform translate operator, on attempts so far,  always returns cancelled. Any attempt to override causes death to blender.